# What is the appropriate preposition of "Radio programme"?

Tags: prepositions

So, in this sentence

> I listened to this conversation (On - In) a radio programme.

What is the appropriate preposition to use?

Comment: Well, "in/on a radio program" is not idiomatic in the US.  It would be "I heard this conversation on the radio", or "I was listening to a program on the radio and I heard this conversation".  ("Conversation" is probably not the right word either, but the proper word would depend on exactly what you heard.)

Comment: I'd suggest 'on the radio', 'during a program'. In TV, you walk about episodes - 'in the episode where Ross turns into a dinosaur' - so maybe 'in an episode of a radio program'. But 'on the radio' seems good enough.

Comment: I choose "on"..

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, I'd say it is most commonly *on* - as in *The Prime Minister was interviewed on the radio this morning*. One would also say *...on the "Today" programme this morning*. But it is not impossible that you might hear *Helen gave birth in last night's episode of the Archers* and even *...Clare Fox regularly appears in the Moral Maze*. Since the *today programme* and *the Moral Maze* are both BBC Radio4 documentary programmes, I am confounded as to why *on* sounds right with one, but *in* with the other. Puzzling.